# Is there a way to show a row in SQL ONLY if SUM returns a certain value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to have only a certain value show when a SUM query is executed? For example, I have a `business_user` table and a `campaigns` table for a charity.

As you can see, business user 2 has 2 active campaigns while business user 1 has 0 active campaigns.

```
mysql> select business_id, active from campaigns;
+-------------+--------+
| business_id | active |
+-------------+--------+
|           2 |      1 |
|           2 |      1 |
|           1 |      0 |
+-------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT b.business_id, SUM(CASE WHEN c.active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active_campaigns
    -> FROM business_users b, campaigns c
    -> WHERE b.business_id = c.business_id
    -> GROUP BY c.business_id;
+-------------+------------------+
| business_id | active_campaigns |
+-------------+------------------+
|           1 |                0 |
|           2 |                2 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Whenever I execute the query above, I want the rows with `active_campaigns = 0` to show and rows with any other value to NOT show. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `HAVING active_campaigns = 0` to the end of the query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.business_id, SUM(CASE WHEN c.active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active_campaigns
FROM business_users b, campaigns c
WHERE b.business_id = c.business_id
GROUP BY c.business_id
Having SUM(CASE WHEN c.active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```